# PyroCMS page children on parent page and including partials/modules on certain pages

Tags: codeigniter, pyrocms

I'm new to CodeIgniter and PyroCMS and I'm stuck on 2 things.

1. How do I make a submenu (navigation) show only on the parent page instead of always showing?
2. What is the best way to include partials/modules on pages without displaying `{pyro:contact:form}` (example) in the editor

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this.

1 Ans: goto design -> Navigation -> Add Navigation Link -> now in target choose the parent page that for submenu.

2 Ans: You don't need to include direct code `{pyro:contact:form}` in pyroCMS you can select Link type (Module/sitelink/url/page) while creating the navigation.

Comment: Thanks! But I already did what you answered on 1. and it shows in all pages. I created a group called "siderbar" and put the children of a parent in there. Then I use this code to `{pyro:navigation:links group="sidebar"}link..{/pyro:navigation:links}` display the links. 2. wasn't exactly what I meant but I'll try some other things